# Turn an Anaconda Python installation into a conda environment to be able to switch between different versions?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, conda

I need to use both Python 2.7, and 3.5. Ideally, I should use conda to create an alternative environment, but after using

`bash Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

to install python 2.7, in a few minutes after downloading the shell script, then with

`conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda`

always failed due to download time out, after more than dozen minutes of downloading numerous packages. (I'm in China, behind GFW.)

But I have no problem to install python 3.5 in a few minutes after downloading the shell script, by

`bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

so I wonder if it's possible to manually turn the python 3.5 installation into a conda managed environment so that I can switch between them?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

set up shadowsocks client and proxchains4, I just set up an ubuntu server .

step1:
  buying or setting up a shadowsocks server

step2:
  install shadowsocks client

```
pip install shadowsocks
```

step3: 
    install proxychains

```
sudo apt-get install proxychains
```

step4: setup and run setup
[shadow socks client tutorial](https://jingsam.github.io/2016/05/08/setup-shadowsocks-http-proxy-on-ubuntu-server.html) and 
 [proxychains tutorial](https://www.proxyrack.com/blog/how-to-chain-socks5-proxies-and-setup-using-srelay-on-ubuntu-16/)

step5: 
you can use proxychains to create new env

```
proxychains conda create -n py35 python=3.5
```

Comment: Hello, please expand your answer to add some explanation.